# Postgresql delete record involving two tables and store this record in the third record

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to delete a record from the table 'student', where on a Cascade delete it will remove it from the 'entry' table. But before delete i need to store this record in the third table 'cancel'.

Here is what i worked out so far:

```
DELETE FROM "CMPS".student
WHERE sno = '1';    

CREATE TRIGGER canceled BEFORE DELETE     
    ON entry    
    FOR EACH ROW    
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_backup_row    

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row(integer)    
    RETURNS trigger AS    
$$    
    BEGIN    
INSERT INTO cancel (eno, excode, sno) values (NEW.eno, NEW.excode, NEW.sno);    
    RETURN NEW;    
    END;    
$$         
   language PLPGSQL
```

But comes back with an errors. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your parameters don't match between the execute and the definition: EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_backup_row   -- no parameter ;  FUNCTION trigger_backup_row(integer)  -- 1 parameter

Comment: Thank you! do i need parameters for all three values?  Like EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_backup_row(integer, char, integer); FUNCTION trigger_backup_row(integer, char, integer). Sorry if silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row()    
    RETURNS trigger AS    
$$    
    BEGIN    
INSERT INTO cancel (eno, excode, sno) values (OLD.eno, OLD.excode, OLD.sno);    
    RETURN OLD;    
    END;    
$$         
   language PLPGSQL
;

CREATE TRIGGER canceled BEFORE DELETE     
    ON entry    
    FOR EACH ROW    
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_backup_row()
;
```

- trigger function do not use arguments
- on delete yo udon't have any `NEW` row - just an `OLD` one

Comment: Thank you! But still not executing.. I'm getting this error all the time.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 13: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row()    
                ^

Comment: got this error..  ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in

Comment: This happens when not having USAGE privilege on any of the schemas of search_path. not related to code

Comment: checkout https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in

Comment: Thanks, so do I do query on schema first: grant usage on schema "CMPS" to public; grant create on schema "CMPS" to public;       And then add to my code: SET search_path TO "CMPS";

Comment: it depends on your structure, but yes - it should work for the statement. also mind SET will change search_path session level only